# JqxScheduler Context menu to select right clicked cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JqxScheduler for schedule appointments.
It seems if we select a cell using left click and right click on different cell jqxScheduler not select that cell where we are right-clicked.
My requirement is reset all cell if the user right clicks on other cell and select that right-clicked.
Have added one solution but it works only once at first time.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var appointments = new Array();

    var appointment1 = {
        id: "id1",
        description: "George brings projector for presentations.",
        location: "",
        subject: "Quarterly Project Review Meeting",
        calendar: "Room 1",
        start: new Date(2015, 10, 23, 9, 0, 0),
        end: new Date(2015, 10, 23, 16, 0, 0)
    }


    appointments.push(appointment1);

    // prepare the data
    var source =
    {
        dataType: "array",
        dataFields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'description', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'location', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'subject', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'calendar', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'start', type: 'date' },
            { name: 'end', type: 'date' }
        ],
        id: 'id',
        localData: appointments
    };
    var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
    $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler({
        date: new $.jqx.date(2015, 11, 23),
        width: 850,
        height: 600,
        source: adapter,
        view: 1,
        showLegend: true,
        /**
         * called when the context menu is created.
         * @param {Object} menu - jqxMenu's jQuery object.
         * @param {Object} settings - Object with the menu's initialization settings.
        */


        /**
         * called when the menu is opened.
         * @param {Object} menu - jqxMenu's jQuery object.
         * @param {Object} the selected appointment instance or NULL when the menu is opened from cells selection.
         * @param {jQuery.Event Object} the open event.
        */
        contextMenuOpen: function (menu, appointment, event) {
            var date = $('.jqx-fill-state-hover').attr('data-date')
            if (date) {
                var d = new Date(date);

                var year = d.getFullYear();
                var month = (d.getMonth() + 1);
                var date = d.getDate();
                var hours = d.getHours();

                var minutes = d.getMinutes();
                $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler('clearSelection');
                $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler('selectCell', new $.jqx.date(year, month, date, hours, minutes));
                console.log(date)
            }
        },
        /**
         * called when the menu is closed.
         * @param {Object} menu - jqxMenu's jQuery object.
         * @param {Object} the selected appointment instance or NULL when the menu is opened from cells selection.
          * @param {jQuery.Event Object} the close event.
       */
        contextMenuClose: function (menu, appointment, event) {
        },
        ready: function () {
            $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler('ensureAppointmentVisible', 'id1');
        },
        resources:
        {
            colorScheme: "scheme02",
            dataField: "calendar",
            source: new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source)
        },
        appointmentDataFields:
        {
            from: "start",
            to: "end",
            id: "id",
            description: "description",
            location: "place",
            subject: "subject",
            resourceId: "calendar"
        },
        views:
            [
                'dayView',
                'weekView',
                'monthView'
            ]
    });


});
```

```html
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />

 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
        <div id="scheduler">
         
        </div>
 
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default functionality provided by JqxScheduler. However you can use below logic,

```
contextMenuOpen: function (menu, appointment, event) {
    var date = $("td[data-selected='true']").attr('data-date');
    alert(date)
}
```

Create an event mousedown in document ready.

```
 $("#scheduler tbody tr td").mousedown(function(e){ 
    if(e.button == 2 ) { 
        $('#scheduler').find('td').each (function() {
            $(this).removeAttr("data-selected");
        });  
        $(this).attr("data-selected","true")
    }
 });
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Working perfectly.